# Export/Import API using Api Manager 2.1

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I've been following [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment) to export my api using Api Manager 2.1., but my api doesn't supposed to have authentication, so I'm trying do like that:

`curl -H "Authorization:None" -X GET "https://localhost:9444/api-import-export-2.1.0-v2/export-api?name=<API_NAME>&version=<API_VERSION>&provider=admin" -k > cFactorTPACSAPI.zip`

I can generate the zip file, but when I try to open it, I receive the follow error message:

> *The archive is either on unknown format or damaged*

Does someone know if the command line is correct when authentication is None?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I've got a solution!

As Pubci commented a had to generate a basic auth for api-import-export application. So, I used [this site](https://www.base64decode.org/) to generate the base64 encoded credentials and worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import an API, you need to call the api-import-export service which is a protected service. As the [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment) explains you need to provide the super tenant or tenant's base 64 encoded credentials. This is nothing to do with the API which you created or trying to export.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How could I create a base 64 encoded credentials?

I've tried use this command line and the zip file has 0KB

curl -H "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -X GET "https://localhost:9444/api-import-export/export-api?name=cFactorTPACS&version=1.0.0&provider=admin" -k > exportedApi.zip

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to provide credentials. **one:** the way you are doing providing Authorization header and @Pubci has suggested currently. You can use postman (chrome extension) to generate base64 credentials using Authorization--basic auth **second:** you can pass using -u switch and type the password on prompt.

here is the export/import commands which works for me. Make sure you provide correct api_name, version and provider_name.  You can get api details using following url (make you login to publisher first before trying this url):
https://:9443/publisher/site/blocks/listing/ajax/item-list.jag?action=getAllAPIs

**To export:**

```
curl -X GET "https://<APIMHost>:9443/api-import-export-2.1.0-v2/export-api?name=HelloWorld&version=v1&provider=admin" > HelloWorld.zip -k -v -u admin
```

**To import:**

```
curl -F file=@"HelloWorld.zip" -k -X POST "https://<APIMHost>:9443/api-import-export-2.1.0-v2/import-api?preserveProvider=false" -v -u admin
```

you can change -u admin with appropriate user name of specific tenant in your environment.

Comment: Glad it worked. please accept the response so that others will know it worked and question is anwered.. :)